# Connecting to RStudio on Linode Server (Ubuntu 16.04) - what username and password?

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04, rstudio-server

We created a small Ubuntu server on Linode, in order to use R + RStudio. Using the Linode guides, we [installed R](https://www.linode.com/docs/development/r/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-and-debian/) and [installed RStudio](https://www.linode.com/docs/development/r/how-to-deploy-rstudio-server-using-an-nginx-reverse-proxy/). In the 2nd link, we're up to step 3 where we need to login to RStudio at `<server-ip-address>:8787/`. Similar to the user from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838443/create-a-username-and-password-in-rstudio-server), we're struggling to login.

To access the server, we are ssh'ing into the server using `ssh root@<server-ip-address>`, and then typing in our password `our-password` when prompted. So we have an IP address, and a password to access the server. I'm not sure what the user is for this server (root?, something else?). In addition to the IP and the server password, I also have a username and password to log into the company's Linode account.

What username / password should I be using to login to RStudio then on the server? root doesn't seem to work. nor did localhost, nor did my username for Linode.

### Edit

Per https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552306-Getting-Started, it seems that RStudio will not permit logins by system users (which, with `root`, I think I am?)

Comment: When you run `id -u <your user name>` at the server command prompt, do you get a number that's lower than 100? Have you set up a non-system user account on your server? Are you trying to connect to the rstudio server before or after you SSH into the server itself.

Comment: I had not setup a non-system user. I set one up and that user has successfully logged into RStudio

Answer (score 0):

After installing RStudio Server (e.g. with PUTTY) you should add a user. Have a look at this youtube video

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRFthoaSLIM
```

ensure that you allocate admin-rights to the user in case you need to use the terminal in RStudio to install a package..